# Align equations on different rows inside tabularray environment

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, alignment, tabularray

I'm trying to find a solution for my problem: align different equations on different rows at their respective equal sign.

I tried the most popular environments for this:

```
eqparbox
equation*
align*
```

but no one works, for different reasons, but still, I need an idea on how to achieve this result.

Apparently the package `tabularray` itself doesn't offer much in terms of options for alignment of different equations.

What to do ?

This is an example of what I have right now

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\def\myformulaone{
    \begin{aligned}
        \mathrm{Area} &= \mathrm{side} \times \mathrm{side}
    \end{aligned}
}
\def\myformulatwo{
    \begin{aligned}
        \mathrm{Perimeter} &= \mathrm{side} \times \mathrm{4}
    \end{aligned}
}
\def\myformulathree{
    \begin{aligned}
        \mathrm{Very Long explanation} &= \mathrm{Area} \times \mathrm{Very Short}
    \end{aligned}
}
\begin{document}
    \noindent%    
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={ll},
            hlines={1pt},
            vlines={1pt}
        }
        {One} & {Two} \\ 
        \SetCell[c=2]{c,$$}{\myformulaone} & \\
        \SetCell[c=2]{c,$$}{\myformulatwo} & \\
        \SetCell[c=2]{c,$$}{\myformulathree} & \\
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest you to insert all equations in a single `align` with many rows. If you insert two `align`s it is impossible to align the equal sign since they are independent.

Comment: @Sigur my final table will add an extra column with 1 `tikzpicture` associated with each formula, so I need them separated for this reason

Comment: you have one-row `aligned` environments which can never do anything useful as there needs to be two rows to have anything to align

Comment: @pafao why not just use align (or perhaps better alignat) and add the tikzpicture to each row of the display?

Comment: if you wa to use tabulararray (or a normal tabular) put the left hand side of each equation in one column, and the right hand side in the next, so the table gives the alignment on = (but I would use `align`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have not managed to make `align` work, I have also read that it could be because `align` is intended to work outside math mode, can you show a complete example ?

Comment: well it's rather hard to guess what you want other than a standard align (of which there are literally thousands of examples on his site), align _starts_ math so yes it is itself not in math but why is that a problem? your `tblr` (which it would replace) is not started in math mode either

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the double dollar sign ( which I needed for the equation itself to start with ) is giving me math mode as in `\SetCell[c=2]{c,$$}{\myformulaone}` . I'm in math mode and I cannot do without apparently .

Comment: but why use a table with cells using $$ instead of using a math display like align?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because there are other parts involved and I need the alignment that only tables can deliver, at least with this low level of complexity, I need equations near figures, near text.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

One possibility is to split equations in two column and write them directly in the table:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vline{1,3,Z}=solid, %vline{2} = {1}{solid},
             colsep = 3pt,
            colspec = {Q[r,m,mode=math] @{\;} Q[l,m,mode=math] X[m,c]},
             row{1} = {mode=text, c},
            }
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    One             
                &       &   Two                                     \\
\mathrm{Area}   & = \mathrm{side} \times \mathrm{side}
                        & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}   \\
\mathrm{Perimeter} 
                & = \mathrm{side} \times 4                        
                        & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}   \\
\mathrm{Very\ Long\ explanation} 
                & = \mathrm{Area} \times \mathrm{Very\ Short}
                        & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's just a 3x3 table ...

Comment: so there isn't a solution with "pure" equations alignment ?

Comment: @pafao, no, as far as know.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer